# Python file locking and scheduling

Tags: python, concurrency, scheduling

I want to solve the following use case with `python`:

- there is a file `foo.txt` that can be edited by various processes
- the file cannot be processed in parallel
- consequently, the processes have to wait until the other processes are ready.

My feeling is that this is a mixture of locking and scheduling. I would like to see something like that:

```py
with blocked("foo.txt"):
    //edit the file
```

During file editing, the file is blocked by this first process. If another process comes with the same code, it has to wait until the first process is ready. The `blocked` method has to store a unique block file that clarifies that the file is blocked. Moreover, it has to ping the folder from time to time to check if the file is still blocked and if he is the next process that is allowed to edit the file.

This is better than pure file blocking as every task can be processed. On the other hand, every process has to use the `with` block to ensure the functionality.

My Questions:

1. Do you know of anything like that (e.g. a package)?
2. Might it make sense to make a package out of that feature? Might be very easy ...

Comment: Can you provide your code so we can help better.